# Accept request at server side jsp from android

Tags: android, jquery, jsp, tomcat

i am working on my project...now the tast i have to accomplish is that

1)i have send request from android application to page which is on tomcat server

2)the page gets request and response to application

**for client side i am using this code**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Creating HTTP client
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Creating HTTP Post
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
            "http://www.example.com/login");

    // Building post parameters
    // key and value pair
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "user@gmail.com"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",
            "Hi, trying Android HTTP post!"));

    // Url Encoding the POST parameters
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // writing error to Log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Making HTTP Request
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        // writing response to log
        Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

}

**but i want to know ...how can i don server side...**
1) i thing i have to make simple page with .jsp extension can do my work ahead

2) **plz guide me little for testing**

```
 a)do i have to switch on wifi of laptop...

 b)and also wifi of my android phone

 c)connect phone through wifi with laptop by IP of laptop

 d)then after connecting throught ip hit localhost server by..."192.168.1.23/file.jsp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using android emulator, you should define server ip address as 10.0.2.2

See->http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html (Network Address Space)

Using a real android device, either by a cabled network, or wireless if android device and server are connected to same network, you should have connectivity by ip, or name if a dns service is providing it.

If device and server are on different networks, you may encounter other difficulties like, routing or firewall problems.

Comment: Actually i am implementing client server modle.In it client is android device(which can b used by any one) and server is on different network..

Comment: Is your HTTP server responding? Try posting data from  html form, or using curl from CLI, if available, and see response.
If you get a response, then you should be able to log in android device.